# Spring boot:Authorization using header before controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am using my spring boot REST API with the controller as follows:-
 `

```
@Autowired
 HazelcastInstance hazelcastinstance;
 String username="VAKSDNDDODM#DLDM#DMOD#DI@#*@EK";
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/Acode/availabile/multiple/{Code}/")
public class MultiController {

    @Resource(name = "AService")
    protected AImpl AService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Response> readMulti(
            @RequestHeader(value="Auth-Token") String token,
            @RequestBody XRequest Request,
            @PathVariable String Code)  throws Exception {
        if(token.equalsIgnoreCase(username))
        {
        Response response = AService.readMultiX(Request, Code);
        }
        else
        {
            response.setMessage("Unauthorized access!");
        response.setStatus(340);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Response>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

`

I wish to do the header comparision before API control enters the controller such that declaring @RequestHeader is not required in controller.Is it possible to do this or do we have an implementation for that?

Comment: If you're using Spring Security, you need to implement a custom AuthenticationFilter + AuthenticationProvider to authenticate using token.

Comment: Well Is there a way to create a dummy Authentication which actually athenticates everyone but only does authorization?